# Looking for Drupal webform tutorial

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, webforms, drupal-theming

I have setup a Drupal site and will work with a designer to customize some [`webform`](http://drupal.org/project/webform)s. Is there any tutorial out there which can help a designer (he also knows some PHP but not a programmer background) to get started? I hope he can learn how to:

- add fields
- theme the form

Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good intro to theming webforms at http://drupal.org/node/79086. That should probably be all he needs, provided he already knows how Drupal theming works.

If not, he should ready http://drupal.org/node/199112, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html and http://drupal.org/theme-guide

Not sure if any instructions are necessary for adding fields to a form and moving them around. It's pretty hard to get wrong.